# Can't open RStudio on ubuntu

Tags: rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I downloaded RStudio on ubuntu 16.04 and in softwares it is shown as installed but I am not able to open it by clicking on it. Also it shows error when i try to open it through terminal-
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Please mention the version of rstudio. Was the user an admin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `sudo apt-get install libuuid1`

Comment: It says libuuid1 is latest version-2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2

Comment: What is your RSudio version that you are installing and is your machine 64bit or 32bit ?

Comment: Rstudio  1.0.143-i386 and machine is 64 bit

Comment: Hi @AmanGupta you are installing 32 bit variant of Rstudio. I would suggest you to install [64bit version](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download3/) and check if it works !

Comment: I am installing 64 bit version, not 32 bit

Comment: Man i386 is 32bit variant.